# Firebase in Firefox Addon: This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firefox-addon

**EDIT:**

I've just noticed that I've caught errors improperly and there is some error:

> This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. \"location.protocol\" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled

And it makes sense, since my page has adress that begin from `moz-extension`.

Are there any workarounds on that?

**Original question:**

I'm building Firefox Extension. It changes the default page that shows up after opening new tab. I want to use Firebase Auth on that page.

Inside html that is being displayed, I've created a button which will be used for Google login. When it's clicked, the following code is executed:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

$("#authenticated_user_content").hide();

$("#google_login").on("click", function() {
  console.log("GOogle login");
  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then(function(result) {
      // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
      var token = result.credential.accessToken;
      // The signed-in user info.
      var user = result.user;
      // ...
      $("#not_logged_in_content").show();
      $("#authenticated_user_content").show();
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // The email of the user's account used.
      var email = error.email;
      // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
      var credential = error.credential;
      // ...
    });
});
```

What happens is: clicking on `#google_login` displays "Google login" message in browser console, but no popup window with Google login form.

Firefox doesn't show any errors in console (after clicking `F12` in browser). I tired going to `about:debugging` and clicked `Debug` next to my extension. New window showed up and displayed this message after clicking `#google_login` button:

> TypeError: can't access dead object

Are there any other ways I could investigate what's wrong? Why popup doesn't show up? Does Firefox block such functionality in webpages displayed by extensions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the Google provider object:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
```

Before

```
firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
```

**Optional**: Specify additional OAuth 2.0 scopes that you want to request from the authentication provider. To add a scope, call addScope. For example:

```
provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly');
```

See the authentication provider [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes). And There are [more options](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#popup-mode)

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, I've already declared provider object. I forgot to paste in in question details, but as you can see, there is `provider` variable in code sample I've shown. Also, if I used undeclared provider, then I would probably see an error. I can't see any errors as I said in my post.

Comment: Your environment is localhost? If so, how you serve ? you serve '$ firebase serve ?

Comment: And did you enabled Google auth with firebase console : https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/providers

Comment: I'm not sure what my environment is. URL doesn't start with `localhost` but with `moz-extension` (see the beginning of my question post). Yes, I've enabled Google Auth in Firebase console.

Comment: Try to use firebase-cli. at root of project serve it at `cmd` with : `firebase serve` and your project will be published at `http://localhost:5000` and within the above warning I think you also need to enable the storage https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/storage/_.appspot.com/files